# One Windows Form needs an access to the components of another. What is the easiest implementation?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

In my project I'm using C++/CLI and `Windows Forms`. I have two Forms. One is executed in main()

```
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application::Run(gcnew FormA);
```

Another **FormB** is executed from the instance of **FormA**

```
FormB^ fb = gcnew FormB();
fb->Show();
```

I need to change components of **FormB** from **FormA**. Normally they are in `private:` section of class FormB. Is there any nice way to do that different from simply making them all public? In Native C++ I would use friend class but it's not allowed in C++/CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++/CLI has an access modifier that native C++ does not have.  You are looking for `internal:`

Empowered by the strong support for modules in .NET.  It is broader than *friend* but you have a pretty hard guarantee that whomever is messing with your private parts is never more than a few cubicles away from yours.  Code that accesses *internal* members must be compiled into the same assembly.  So your FormB class must be in the same project as your FormA class.  The common case.

If you need the equivalent of *friend* across modules then you need the [InternalsVisibleTo] attribute.  Exposing members with a public property would be another common way.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like using _internal_ is nicer solution than just _public_.

Answer (score 1):

While providing public access to FormB's members may seem like a quick and easy solution, I would advise you to add some methods on FormB to perform said actions.

This way, you can call those methods from FormA, and at the same time retain proper encapsulation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I considered this possibility. But too many components thus too much work.